# Avoiding ASP.NET passwords in github?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svn, git, passwords

I understand this question can be general but, specifically with regards to ASP.NET MVC, what's the best way to keep passwords locally but not in git/svn? My database connection string is currently in web.config -- is it best to somehow include a file in web.config that isn't in git? What do you folks do?

Comment: On think that comes to mind is setting svn:ignore on web.config and including web.config.sample instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use Windows Auth with my databases, so the connection string contains a server name but not a username/password.

For Machines where I can't use Windows Auth, I use [web.config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) and add the web.dev.config to my .gitignore.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding Git, I would use a [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) in order to build the right web.config out of:

- a `web.config.template` file,
- an *external* (encrypted) source where to look for the password.

[image]

On every checkout, the '`smudge`' script would be the right `web.config` content, that way:

- `web.config` remains private (only visible in your working tree)
- common parts of the `web.config` which don't change often and are public information remain versioned in `web.config.template`.
- the password, even encrypted, don't get replicated from repository to repository.

Answer (score 0):

put the web.config in your .gitignore file. The web.config will not change very often.